# JQuery Flot setData don't set data correctly

Tags: jquery, flot

I'm having trouble to do a real time graph with jquery-flot (flotcharts).

Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var test = function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "index.json",
        datatype:"json"
    }).always(function(series) {
        console.log(series);
        update(series.responseText);
    });
};

var options = {
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time"
    }
};
var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), [{label:"test",data:[[1389185414000,0],[1389185415000,15449]]}], options);
function update(series) {
    console.log(series);
    plot.setData(series);
    console.log(plot.getData());
    plot.setupGrid();
    plot.draw();
    setTimeout(test, 100000);
}
test();
});
```

The issue seems to be with the setdata function. Here is what I get from ajax request :

```
[{
    label: "test",
    data: [
        [1389185414000, 0],
        [1389185415000, 15449],
        [1389185425000, 1406],
        [1389185435000, 187],
        [1389185445000, 1377],
        [1389185455000, 1544],
        [1389185465000, 270],
        [1389185475000, 1681],
        [1389185485000, 687]
    ]
}]
```

Then, if I look at what is returned by plot.getData, a new object is created for each character in the returned json string. (ex: an object for "[", one for "{", one for "l", and so on.)

Any idea of what I might do wrong ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass a string to setData; it expects an array.

The reason why you have a string is because you didn't capitalize the `t` in `datatype`, and so jQuery is not interpreting your data as JSON.

Comment: That **dataType** is definitely the OP's problem.  An `$.ajax` call with a `json` dataType shouldn't even have a `.responseText` property.